How to solve "Uncaught (in promise)" console error?
I'm editing a website for a client because the previous guy botched the case. I'm using Elementor and when I try to save changes to the header settings, when I press the button nothing happens and the console returns the following message:screen of my console
I tried to read about it on the Internet, but I couldn't find a solution. I don't even know what to do because I have absolutely no experience when it comes to solving console problems.
What could be the reason for this? Is this some problem with Elementor installation? After entering one of the links in the console, I received information about lack of permissions 401, but I definitely have these permissions because I am an administrator. I scanned the website using Wordfence, it didn't detect anything, it's probably not the viruses fault.
Thanks!
I tried to ignore the problem, tried logging in on different devices. I tried logging in to different Wordpress accounts with administrator privileges and scanning the site for viruses.

Have you checked the debug log yet? If not then it might be a good idea to do so, it might give you some clues. Alternatively, consider reaching out to Elementor's support team and ask them for assistance with this.
